# How do I override the terminal command "rm" to perform the "rm -i" command by default?

Tags: terminal, command-line, macos

The command `rm` nukes files.

`rm -i` asks for confirmation before nuking the files.

When I use `rm`, I want `rm -i` to happen.

Comment: I used to work under a sysadmin who was a big fan of `rm -i`, so he added it as an alias on every server. The upshot was that I and everyone else working with him developed a practice of running `rm -rf` when emptying a directory rather than the safer `rm -r`, which will refuse to delete read-only files. You may think that `rm -i` makes you safer, but in my experience the opposite is the case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Use an [*Alias*](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/bash-aliases-mac-centos-linux-unix.html).

> The alias command allows the user to launch any command or group of
> commands (including options and filenames) by entering a single word

```
alias rm="rm -i"
```

The next time you issue the command `rm` it will issue `rm -i`

You can also make a new alias in case you want to keep `rm` functioning as it does by default.  To create a new alias

```
alias rmi="rm -i"
```

Now, `rm` will have it's default behavior and `rmi` will have the `-i` option

To make it permanent, just add it to your `~/.bash_profile`.  This way, everytime you open a new shell, your alias will be ready to go.

Comment: or you can unalias `rm` by prepending `rm` with a backward slash  `\rm` and it follows the default behavior.

Comment: fd0, Your comment, "_or you can unalias `rm` by prepending `rm` with a `\rm` and it follows the default behavior._" is not accurate. To _unalias_ an _alias_ you use `unalias name`, In a Terminal type `help unalias`. Now if one has named an _alias_ the same as a _binary executable_ and one wants to run the _binary executable_ instead of the same named _alias_, then one can stop **_alias expansion_** by prepending a `\\` backslash and in doing so one is not unalias-ing the _alias_, the _alias_ still exists.

Comment: @user3439894 Agree, I should have phrased it "you can temporarily unalias". BTW, `help unalias` returns an error message in my shell.

Comment: @fd0, What _shell_ are you using? `unalias` is a _bash shell_ built-in and in OS X the default _shell_, `help unalias` returns: "unalias: unalias [-a] name [name ...]  Remove NAMEs from the list of defined aliases.  If the -a option is given, then remove all alias definitions." The key point here is using a "\" to stop _alias expansion_ not unalias the _alias_, not even temporarily as it implies having to reset the _alias_. I know it somewhat _antics with semantics_ however it's important to understand the difference between (temporarily) stoping _alias expansion_ vs. unalias-ing the _alias_.